# Download zip and save unzip

Tags: javascript, python, django, react-native, zip

I´m working with an react native app that use a rest created in django. This app has an offline mode, for that reason I need be able to download zip files from the server to be played when offline mode will work.

I've already tried using the `dload` library from python it works downloading and unziping the file but it download the file in the same script path (server). I need to save the zip file in the phone.
Actual code looks like this...

```
def download(request):
    url ="https://someirl/sco1.zip"
    dload.save_unzip(url, "../../")
    return HttpResponse( content_type="application/json")
```

According with `dload` documentation second parameter in save_unzip is the folder when the zip will be downloaded and unzipped ¿How can I made to download on the phone?

If you know a better way using Django or react native I would be pleasure to testing it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the service worker with the offline mode and cache your files directly in the cache and play from them later

[Service worker and offline mode](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline)

Comment: Because the files that I need injects js code to save info in a local database when the user is using the app